# Verify from the definition of the limit of a sequence problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Please help me to prove that $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^4}{n!} = 0$$
I really need help with approximating $\frac{n^4}{n!}$ and find something that is greater than $\frac{n^4}{n!}$, that will make it easier to determine a value for N, in order to show that $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow$ $\frac{n^4}{n!}$<$\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $n$ be not too small (soon we will be more precise). Then 
$$\frac{n^4}{n!}\le \frac{n^4}{(n)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}.$$
If $n\ge 8$, then $n-1$, $n-2$, $n-3$, and $n-4$ are all $\ge \frac{n}{2}$.
It follows that if $n\ge 8$ then
$$\frac{n^4}{n!}\le \frac{16}{n}.$$
(And indeed it is quite a bit less than $\frac{16}{n}$, but the above inequality is plenty good enough for our purposes.)